# Angular 7 app on Internet Explorer returning XML5619: Incorrect document syntax error

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I have an angular 7 app that runs fine on Chrome (no browser errors), but when i try to open it using IE11, i get the following error: "XML5619: Incorrect document syntax.". I googled and found some people solving this by setting up the content-type on the ajax request they are doing. But in this case, i am only visiting the app's home page, so i am not doing explicit ajax requests. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Check [this link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9).

Comment: i did uncomment all the required imports and installed the 2 libraries required already. still getting this error for xml.

Comment: What's the Angular CLI 7 version, using the latest version? What did you do will meet this error? Just using the Angular CLI to create a new angular 7 application? I tried to create a new app, it seems that everything works well on my IE 11. can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: angular 7.0.1 and CLI 7.0.3 and TS 3.1.6. Works on Chrome. On IE i get the error mentioned. I uncomment some modules to load them on the polyfills.ts file, and execute the npm i commands mentioned there. all done.
I did not uncomment the lines in relation with disabling parts of the domevents and zone enable cross context check. [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FoRMFKNt1xK9FqukWrWEJwD6kw3bIUsDhJsXcEnkTkw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Still not sure why and where you meet this error, it seems that I use the same polyfill with your's, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So that we could test it on our side.